# How to retrieve an EF POCO property display value from EdmProperty

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an application that is translated and all properties in my POCO's are marked like this

```
[Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resources), Name = "Name")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

At runtime I want to reflect on the property and get it's resource value, like this.

```
EdmProperty prop = entityType.Properties.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name.Equals("Name", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
```

At this point I want to be able to get the Name annotation from this EdmProperty, and that's where am stuck. I have tried to look at the source file for the EdmProperty and I can't seem to find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
if(prop.Documentation != null && !prop.Documentation.IsEmpty)
{
   var displayName = prop.Documentation.Summary;
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer to prevent deletion (code-only / link-only answers are more likely to get deleted).

Comment: It's returning null on all properties.